# How can I use an excel file for data testing on a mac

Tags: ruby, excel, automated-tests, browser-automation

I am trying to use an excel file that has data such as first name, last name, hire date, department, etc. to populate fields in a web browser. Is there something on a mac that can do this.

I have seen something like:

```
require 'win32ole'
require 'excel'
```

The 'win32ole' gem only seems to work on Windows.
And I can't find the 'excel' gem anywhere.
Anything known would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the spreadsheet gem:

> http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/

That can read Excel files.

Alternatively, you could convert your spreadsheets to CSV and then use the [standard CSV libraries](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/index.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you point me in the direction of some good examples or tutorials for using the spreadsheet gem?

Comment: @Dave: You could put that down as an answer so that future searchers might find it. And maybe tell the roo author to tone down his color scheme before someone goes blind.

Comment: +1 for both adding this as an answer and for color scheme. :)